# Как nginx определяет что статика, а что нет?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Здравствуйте. По советам хочу поставить nginx в качестве front-end для Apache. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как nginx будет определять что статика, а что нет?
Например, я обращаюсь по адресу /account, в .htaccess у меня прописаны правила, но поймёт ли nginx что это не статика?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx не отличает статику от динамики. Вы просто задаете правило обработки статики по расширению (css, js, jpg, etc...), а остальные запросы отправляете на прокси (apache или fpm).
Nginx не работает с .htaccess
Так же вы можете настроить правило с try_files. Nginx будет пытаться отдать статику, а если файл не найден, например, перенаправлять запрос на apache или ответить ошибкой.